# my stupid image broke

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

I think I broke something ughh im so angry my stupid image got CORRUPTED. Please help me fix it

[image]

(this is my first puzzle so feedback/retagging appreciated)

Comment: maybe the steganography tag?

Comment: Please don't change a question after an answer was posted: ask a better question next time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> YOU WIN

HOW?

> There are three images that can be found by editing the page. Comparing the differences of the first two images of static showed the Hex code 0C 7D C7 C3 D9 56 1B AB E6. The third image was the corrupted image. I opened this one in a hex editor and found the characters CORRUPTED at location B8 through C0. I replaced all of the hex in that area with the hex from the first two images. After reopening the image I was greeted with the text "you win"

Answer (score 2):

The hidden message is

> **you win**
>
>  Strangely, I could only detect it by downloading and viewing it in another image viewer.

Comment: rot13(bxnl gungf jrveq va zl ivrjre vg fubhqyag qvfcynl nal bs gur grkg? jung vzntr ivrjre qvq lbh hfr?)

Comment: oh i caught the problem my bad id have to redo the puzzle to fix it

Comment: rot13(Lrf! Jung vzntr ivrjre qvq lbh hfr?)

Comment: In [FastStone](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm) image viewer (no affiliation).

Comment: @violetorigin are you saying you will change the question after an answer was posted?

Comment: i wont change the question but orvat noyr gb frr gur grkg qrsrngf gur checbfr. lbh pna fgvyy gel naq fbyir vg gur abezny jnl v thrff vyy whfg nqq na rqvg

Comment: @violetorigin please don't do that: I answered the question as posted. If you want to improve the question, you can code another message and ask a new question.

Comment: im not changing the contents of the problem dw im just adding a note i made a mistake